# What does '/1' stands for in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I recently started studying and working with Prolog for an application where logic programming is very suited for. In particular, I am woroking with SWI-Prolog (v. 7.6.4, amd64) and Etalis (v. 1.1), an extension for prolog.

What I am not understading is the meaning of: /0, /1, and even /2, /3, that I found in examples during the definition of custom predicates. Most of the prolog directives are defined by directive_name/1.

So, what do these numbers stand for?

Comment: When you get to [definite clause grammars](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=DCG) (DCGs), you'll start to see two slashes, like `integer//1`, which means it is a DCG rule of 1 argument (but under the hood, a rule with 3 arguments).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simply the number of arguments.

For example, append/3 means append(A1, A2, A3).

Comment: Now it makes sense. Thank you, very appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This number is called the *arity*, it is the number of arguments a *predicate*, or *functor* takes. A *constant* is in fact a fuctor with zero arity, so `/0`.

The name of a predicate together with the arity identify a specific predicate. For example the `member/2` predicate is diffrent from the `append/2` predicate, and the `append/3` predicate is different from the `append/2` predicate.